# How can I implement touch scroll animations like iphone in WPF?"

Tags: wpf

I have implemented a paging list like this

View

```
<Window x:Class="TouchScrollTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchScrollTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Peoples}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPeople}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="4" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#222222" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Border CornerRadius="30" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="80" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Width="120" Content="Previous" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}" />
            <Button Width="120" Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TouchScrollTest
{
    public class People : ObservableObject
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
        }
        private string name;

        private People(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public static People CreateInstance(string name)
        {
            return new People(name);
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private static readonly int defaultPage = 1;

        public ObservableCollection<People> Peoples => new(peoples.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * 4).Take(4));

        private List<People> peoples;

        private int TotalPages => peoples == null ? 0 : (int)Math.Ceiling((double)peoples.Count / 4);

        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get => currentPage;
            private set
            {
                SetProperty(ref currentPage, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Peoples));
            }
        }
        private int currentPage = defaultPage;

        public ICommand PreviousCommand { init; get; }

        public ICommand NextCommand { init; get; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            PreviousCommand = new RelayCommand(Previous);
            NextCommand = new RelayCommand(Next);

            var sample = new List<People>()
            {
                People.CreateInstance("Ethan Johnson"),
                People.CreateInstance("Olivia Smith"),
                People.CreateInstance("Noah Williams"),
                People.CreateInstance("Emma Brown"),
                People.CreateInstance("Liam Jones"),
                People.CreateInstance("Ava Davis"),
                People.CreateInstance("James Miller"),
                People.CreateInstance("Charlotte Wilson"),
                People.CreateInstance("Benjamin Taylor"),
                People.CreateInstance("Sophia Martinez"),
            };
            peoples = sample;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Peoples));
        }

        private void Previous()
        {
            if (CurrentPage > defaultPage)
            {
                CurrentPage--;
                return;
            }
            CurrentPage = TotalPages; // Rolling page
        }

        private void Next()
        {
            if (CurrentPage < TotalPages)
            {
                CurrentPage++;
                return;
            }
            CurrentPage = defaultPage; // Rolling page
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement a scroll animation similar to the iPhone.
When scrolling from left to right or right to left on a touch screen, the items of the next page appear from the opposite direction and the previous pages disappear.

How should I approach implementing such animation? I need ideas.

I tried to apply animation when notifyonsourceupdated of ItemsSource occurs, but failed.